# How can I build a stand alone R engine with some packages included?

Tags: r

I have a windows server that does not allow me to install anything but it allows me to run exe files (Meaning that I cannot simply download the R installation package and install R that way). I want to run R on it and I like to know if it is possible for me to make an R.exe with some packages like ggplot and lattice included?

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot save any files anywhere on the server?

Comment: I can store files on the server

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any filestore on the server? I can't imagine that you wouldn't have. You can install packages to any directory, which can then be your own personal library. Look at the `help(install.packages)` and `help(library)` and there's a `lib` or `lib.loc` argument that tells it where to stick it.

If the reason you can't install is because `install.packages` can't get through the network to CRAN, then download the binary from CRAN, transfer it to the server, and install that way.

Note that I didn't answer your question about building an R exe with bundled packages (here's that answer: "No") because you thought the answer to that question was the solution to your real problem ("I can't install packages"). Always ask a question to your original problem...

Comment: I think you have answered a completely different problem than mine. I cannot install R. So my question is what should I do to have a stand alone Rscript and R.exe on that computer.

Comment: Wow, that's really harsh. "Get your admins to install R" is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the portable version of R that could do it for me. It generates a folder that can be moved to the new server.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/